# Android postDelay method's reliability

Tags: android, timer, postdelayed

I am using android.os.Handler's “postDelayed” method to turn ON and OFF a relay. There are 2 runnable - one for sending ON command and another for sending OFF command. The relay needs to be kept on for fixed ms and turned OFF for fixed ms again.

I referred this old android post 
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html
to send repeating commands to the relay

The start command needs to be sent at the same time from different devices - each connected to a different relay. So the effect should be that all relays should turn ON at the same time.

I ensure that the command is sent at the same time from each device, using GPS time sync on all devices. Once all devices are GPS time synced, I send ON command at start of second for the first time and then add the fixed delays to the postDelay methods in both runnables.

I still notice that the relays are not turned ON at the same time the first time itself. I notice a delay upto 1 sec.

I need to know how reliable is "postDelayed" method? Can I trust it for a precision upto 5 ms?
Is there a more reliable way to send a repeating command at a fixed delay?

Here is part of the code

```
public class RelayAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean>
    {
        private Activity context = null;
        private Handler handler = null;
        private Runnable offRunnable,onRunnable;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            handler = new Handler();
            onRunnable = new Runnable() {
                               
                                @Override
                                 public void run() {
                                               new RelayTurnOnAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);
                                               publishProgress(1);  // used to display on UI that a command has been sent
                                               handler.postDelayed(offRunnable, 500);
                                      
                                }
                        };

            offRunnable = new Runnable() {
                               
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                               new RelayTurnOffAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);
                                               publishProgress(2);  // used to display on UI that a command has been sent
                                               handler.postDelayed(onRunnable, 1000);
                                                
                                       
                                }
                         };
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Code to calculate diff when first ON command should be sent
                .
                .
                handler.postDelayed(onRunnable, diff);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            switch (values[0]) {
            case 0:
            {
                break;
            }
            case 1:
            {   //code to update UI
                .
                .
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {   //code to update UI
                .               .
                .
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
            }

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

I also notice a delay upto 10 ms when  RelayTurnOnAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null) is called.

Comment: post your code how you use. your Handler

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it directly without asynctask.

I mean if all you do in `doInBackground` is call `postDelayed` then you can do it directly on UI thread and inside handler runnable instead of `publishProgress` directly set progress.

Comment: I am also calculating difference and start of sec besides just calling the postDelayed method inside doInBackground. I don't think calling postDelayed from UI thread will improve performance.

Comment: Also if I remove asynctask, and send relay command on UI thread, UI will hang if relay gets unresponsive for even a few ms.